# What's a good approach to show "Success" or "Error" jquery dialogs?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter

I'm using PHP CodeIgniter with jQuery.

Say for example I have a `<table>` (of employees perhaps). 
Now above the said table I have an "Add Employee" button.
This button opens a `jQuery-dialog` with the `<form>`. When this form submits, it goes server-side of course (validates whether a duplicate entry or not), then it's sent back to corresponding view with the updated table.

What I want to do is to show a dialog that an employee is successfully added or that it is a duplicate entry.

I'm doing this by

```
appname/controller/action?addSuccess=true
```

or

```
appname/controller/action?addSuccess=false
```

everytime I return back to the view, then on my page, in my `$(document).ready()` I check for such query string and opens the corresponding dialog (success or error dialog). My problem now is that, if I refresh the page (same url) I get the dialogs again (although nothing happens serverside).

**QUESTION**: Is this approach good enough? Any good advice to improve this? :)

Thanks a lot!.

Comment: The title of this question has me speechless.  Please change it to something more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing that info as a query parameter, why not store that info Code Igniters flash data. This data gets persisted across only one redirect. The next time you reload the page, the data will not be set (as CI will automatically remove it for you) and you wouldnt accidentally display the warning.

- Form is submitted to server. Set appropriate value in CI's flash message system.
- Redirect to another url? Or maybe display another view.
- In the view html, use php to read that flash message value and set an appropriate value in javascript.
- Read that js value and accordingly display the popup/modal/message.
- The flash message data will be removed automatically by CI at next page refresh.

Some sample code meant for the redirected view html: (I dont do php...)

```
var shouldDisplayWarning = "<? php code that sets some value based on flash variable ?>";
if (shouldDisplayWarning === "yes") {
  displayWarning();
}
```

Further reading: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html (half way down the page they mention flash data.)

Comment: I like your idea :) Thanks sir. Although you can edit your code above to emphasize (for other readers) that you should "remove" the data from session.

Comment: Well, one really shouldnt be using session for storing one off data. Thats what flash data is meant for. I mentioned session, purely because at the time I wasnt aware if CI actually had flash data or not. In Asp.Net MVC they are referred to as TempData. I think I will just not mention session. You could then mark it as the answer :)

Comment: nice, im liking flashdata :) thanks for the answer and for the new knowledge :)